# Sequence of function and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We can easily find example of sequence of function which is convergent but not uniformly convergent on any closed and bounded interval.

My question is: can we find a sequence of function which is convergent everywhere, but not uniformly convergent on any infinite set?

Definitely I am assuming infinite set under consideration has no isolated points.

Comment: If it's convergent everywhere, it's convergent on any infinite set. Please clarify

Comment: @Tryss I have corrected the question

Comment: By Egoroff's theorem, we see that your sequence must consist of nonmeasurable functions, if it exists at all.

Comment: @PhoemueX thanks for hint. Egoroff's theorem is valid for finite measure set. Now if consider sequence of function which are characteristic function on [n, infinity) we get it converges to 0 function but doesn't converge uniformly only on any set which is complement of set of positive measure. But I am not sure about any infinite set

Comment: If all $f_n$ are measurable, apply Egoroff on the restriction of the $f_n$ to (e.g.) $(0,1)$. This yields a set of positive measure (which is hence infinite) on which the convergence is uniform.

Comment: sorry didn't get hint. @PhoemueX would it imply we can define function which I have asked

Answer (score 1):

The answer is : there is no such sequences of functions.

Let's start by a lemma :

**Lemma** : Let $E = \left\lbrace u \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} : u_{n+1} \geq u_n \right\rbrace$ be the set of increasing sequences. **for all** $S\subset E$ with  $\text{card}(S) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, it exist a an infinite subset $B$ of $S$ such as  $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \: \sup \lbrace u_k : u \in B \rbrace < +\infty$

**Proof** : check the answer by user28111 here : [Does it always exist an infinite subset of sequences that satisfy this property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165801/does-it-always-exist-an-infinite-subset-of-sequences-that-satisfy-this-property/1165846?noredirect=1#1165846)

Then the main proof :

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n \to f$. We define

$$B_{i,j} = \bigcap_{n=j}^{\infty}\left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{i} \right\rbrace$$

Remark that $B_{i,j} \subset B_{i,j+1}$

and a function $\psi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$

$$\psi(x)_i = \inf \left\lbrace j : x\in B_{i,j} \right\rbrace$$

1. If $\psi(\mathbb{R})$ is at most countable, $ \exists u \in \psi(\mathbb{R}), \psi^{-1}(\lbrace u \rbrace)$ is uncountable. Let's take $S= \psi^{-1}(\lbrace u \rbrace)$.

We now show that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$ :

Let's take an arbitrary $x$ in $S$. By definition of $\psi$, $\forall x\in S, \forall i\in \mathbb{N}^*, x \in B_{i,u_i}$. Hence

$$ x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i,u_i} $$

i.e.

$$\forall i \in \mathbb{N}^*, \exists u_i \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq u_i, \forall x \in S, |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{i}$$

$f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$

2. If $\psi(\mathbb{R})$ is uncountable, we use the lemma on $\psi(\mathbb{R})$ and we call $U$ the resulting set. Let's take $S = \phi^{-1}(U)$. Notice that $S$ is also infinite

We now show that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$ . First we define the sequence $v$ :

$$v_n = \sup \lbrace u_n : u\in U \rbrace$$

Let's take an arbitrary $x$ in $S$. we have that $\forall x\in S, \forall i\in \mathbb{N}^*, x \in B_{i,v_i}$. Indeed, as $v_i \geq \psi(x)_i$,

$$x \in B_{i,psi(x)_i} \subset B_{i,v_i}$$

Then

$$x \in \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} B_{i,v_i}$$

i.e.

$$\forall i \in \mathbb{N}^*, \exists v_i \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq v_i, \forall x \in S, |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{i}$$

$f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $S$

Comment: Very nice! Just one small remark: As observed by user28111 in the answer to the linked post, you do not need ${\rm card}(S) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, you just need that $S$ is uncountable. If you truly needed ${\rm card}(S) = 2^{\aleph_0}$, then your proof would (at least as written) depend on the continuum hypothesis (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).